# Graph of weakly continuous linear operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, closed-graph

I have a few questions regarding the graph of an operator. Consider the operator $T:X \rightarrow Y$ between Banach spaces $X,Y$. Assume that $T$ is a linear operator which is (weak, weak)-continuous, so $T$ is continuous when $X$ and $Y$ are endowed with the weak topology. Consider the graph $G(T) := \{(x,y) \in X \times Y: ~~Tx = y \}$. The two questions I have are:

Can we conclude that $G(T)$ is weakly closed subspace of $X \times Y$? Also, since $G(T)$ is convex can we then use Mazur's Theorem to conclude that $G(T)$ is strongly closed in $X \times Y$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The general fact, that a continuous map between Hausdorff topological spaces has closed graph implies that $G(T)$ is closed in $(X,\sigma(X,X^*))\times (Y,\sigma(Y,Y^*) = (X\times Y, \sigma(X\times Y,(X\times Y)^*))$.

You do not need Mazur's theorem to conclude that $G(T)$ is strongly closed: The strong (or norm-) topology on $X\times Y$ is *finer* than the weak topology and thus has more closed sets. (Mazur says the converse for convex sets.)

Comment: @user1294729 I now agree with you that ["every weak open is also norm open"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616482), and this is the same as what Jochen says here. Hence the "literature" was wrong to use convexity+a powerful remark to argue that if Gr(T) is weakly closed then it is norm-closed. This is trivial. Please, what was this book?